# Setting the value of a cell, vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, set

I have a simple question regarding setting the value a cell in excel using vba.

The following code doesn't work, could anyone help me with it?

```
Thisworkbook.sheets("name1").range("I"& 4 +k).value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & k)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Do you have a sheet called "name1" in your workbook? What is the value of k?

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("name1").Range("I" & (4 +k)).Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D" & k).Value
```

How's that?
The brackets around `(4 + k)` will help the calculation, and the `.Value` at the end will allow the value to be taken across.